# Yii2 renderPartial view in Layout

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to render a view to my layout on yii2 but I get an error

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Undefined variable: dataProvider
```

I create a controller category with function

```
public function Wdgcategory()
    {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Category::find(),
        ]);

        return $this->renderPartial('wdgCategory', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

And in my view I create a view file in category/wdgCategory.php

```
    <?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ListView;

?>

<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemOptions' => ['class' => 'item'],
    'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
        return '<li>'
                .Html::a(Html::encode($model->category_name),
                ['view', 'id' => $model->category_id])
                .'<li>';
    },
]) ?>
```

and in layout I add this code

```
<ul>
    <?= $this->render('/category/wdgCategory') ?>
</ul>
```

but I get error : **Undefined variable: dataProvider**

Comment: Why you're rendering `wdgCategory` view from layout? It is already rendered by `renderPartial()` from controller action.

Comment: you need to add the variable `dataProvider` to your render call: `<?= $this->render('/category/wdgCategory', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]) ?>`

Comment: is not working, I want to create a vertical menu in layout from categories

Comment: rob006 : I'm not using action : public function Wdgcategory(); I'm using public function 
i want to create vertical menu in layout from category table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have defined `Wdgcategory()` method but you're never using it. You're just trying to render view from layout without providing necessary data (`$dataProvider`).

In your case you should probably create widget for this list:

```
class CategoriesWidget extends \yii\base\Widget {

    public function run() {
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Category::find(),
        ]);

        return $this->render('categories', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And use it in your layout:

```
<?= CategoriesWidget::widget() ?>
```